# How to detect scrollable layouts on main view using culebra GUI

Tags: androidviewclient

I am trying to record steps for running a UI test using Culebra but I am unable to get items from bottomsheet layout opened on the main view in my app.

I have tried clicking on the option but the code generated has no information about the bottomsheet layout option that was clicked.

I expect to get all the items in the bottomsheet and when i click on it I should get the code generated for that particular textview in the entire layout.

Answer (score 0):

This is a `culebra` generatred script where I added a check for `isScrollable()` at the end

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Copyright (C) 2013-2018  Diego Torres Milano
Created on 2019-05-06 by Culebra v15.5.1
                      __    __    __    __
                     /  \  /  \  /  \  /  \ 
____________________/  __\/  __\/  __\/  __\_____________________________
___________________/  /__/  /__/  /__/  /________________________________
                   | / \   / \   / \   / \   \___
                   |/   \_/   \_/   \_/   \    o \ 
                                           \_____/--<
@author: Diego Torres Milano
@author: Jennifer E. Swofford (ascii art snake)
"""


import re
import sys
import os

from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient

TAG = 'CULEBRA'

_s = 5
_v = '--verbose' in sys.argv


kwargs1 = {'ignoreversioncheck': False, 'verbose': False, 'ignoresecuredevice': False}
device, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit(**kwargs1)
kwargs2 = {'forceviewserveruse': False, 'useuiautomatorhelper': False, 'ignoreuiautomatorkilled': True, 'autodump': False, 'debug': {}, 'startviewserver': True, 'compresseddump': True}
vc = ViewClient(device, serialno, **kwargs2)

vc.dump(window='-1')

com_google_android_apps_nexuslauncher___id_apps_list_view = vc.findViewByIdOrRaise("com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher:id/apps_list_view")
print "scrollable? ", com_google_android_apps_nexuslauncher___id_apps_list_view.isScrollable()
```